# PopUp Menu Inflate Exception in Recycler view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, popupmenu, inflate-exception

I have a fragment with Recycler view

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview, container, false);
ViewGroup fragmentview=(ViewGroup)getView();
    dashboardcontentList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new DashboardAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), dashboardcontentList);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
```

Recycler view is inflated properly but I have a pop menu in each card of the recycler view.

But the popup menu binder is throwing a infateException

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    dashboardcontent dashboardcontent = dashboardcontentList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(dashboardcontent.getName());
    Glide.with(mContext).load(dashboardcontent.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);
    holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);
        }
    });
}

/**


 * Showing popup menu when tapping on 3 dots
     */
    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        // inflate menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_album, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
        try{
        popup.show();}
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The same adapter when its called from another activity (Homeactivity) popup menu works fine but from the fragment(contained in welcomeactivity) it is throwing inflate exception.

AndroidManifest file

```
<application
        android:name=".medipal.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.Welcome"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"              android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.HelpScreen" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Recyclerview"
            android:label="Recyclerview"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.contacts">


</manifest>
```

I expect the output to be something like 
[when the menu button is clicked I see a crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n53gb.png)

a

```
ndroid.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x379 "res/drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_material.xml" a=1 r=0x10803d9}
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:93)
                                                       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.measureIndividualMenuWidth(MenuPopup.java:160)
                                                       at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:153)
                                                       at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:187)
                                                       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290)
                                                       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:175)
                                                       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:141)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:233)
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call `findViewById()` directly for Activity, however as you are using a Fragment, youo will need a view object to call `findViewById()`. eg. `getView().findViewById();`.

1. [View - findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29)
2. [Activity - findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29)

new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);

> new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);

Here popup menu requires `Context`, passed as first parameter. You can use `this` if you are in activity, however in Fragment you need to use `getActivity()` instead of `this`

Use `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` instead of just `getApplicationContext()` whenever you want to display `Toast` from `Fragment`.

Please use below code. I hope you get your solution:

```
public void popup_window() {

View menuItemView = getView().findViewById(R.id.menu_popup); PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), menuItemView); popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_, popupMenu.getMenu());

popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {  
            case R.id.action_ticket:  
                Intent intdn = new Intent(getActivity(),List_Activity.class); // Your nxt activity name instead of List_Activity
                intdn.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);                   
                getActivity().startActivity(intdn);
              break;    

            case R.id.action_survey:  
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Under Construction ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                break;      
            case R.id.action_service_request:  
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Under Construction ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                break;  

              default: 
                  break;  

        }  
         return true;
    } }); popupMenu.show(); }
```

**For more detail please [Check this tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/create-options-menu-recyclerview-item-tutorial/).**

Comment: Tried it I am doing the same thing but still the code breaks at popup.show().

I am calling this from a fragment the same when I call from another activity the issue is not there.